# Is there a more compact syntax for TryFind?

Tags: c#, f#, coding-style

I am using a using Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Collections.FSharpMap
and very often have to write:

```
var oo = world.Entity.TryFind(t);
var entity = oo == null ? null : oo.Value;
```

And similar.  Any suggestions for a better style?

Comment: Just curious: why wouldn't you use `Dictionary`, or even better, F#?

Comment: In my particular case I need a persistent map implementation to record snapshots of historic changes efficiently and the project is largely C# already.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could write an [Extension Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx):

```
public static T ValueOrDefault<T>(this FSharpOption<T> option)
{
    return option == null ? default(T) : option.Value;
}
```

Usage:

```
var entity = world.Entity.TryFind(t).ValueOrDefault();
```

Comment: this is nice, i usually do this with .net types that might return a null to wrap in option., basically if null then none else some n...